# How to stop an image disappearing with the div it's in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made this [site/webapp](http://www.littlethings.me.uk/app/recipe/shepherdspie/game.html) and you can drag the onion out of the white space it's in and onto anywhere on the page but, when you click the button at the left side it disappears when the rest of the div it was/is in. How can I make it not disappear when the user drags it out of the white box?

I used jQuery to make it slide out and in:

```
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
      $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "slide" );
    });
```

and this html to make it work:

```
   <button id="button">&lt;-&gt;</button>
    <aside class="ingredients" id="toggle">
        <section class="center">
            <section class="onion" id="draggable"></section>
            <section class="butter"></section>
        </section>
    </aside>
```

The sections use background images to make them appear:

```
.onion {
    background-image: url(onion.png);
    margin: 20px auto -300px auto;
}

.choppedonion {
    background-image: url(choppedonion.png);
}
```

Comment: Try just sliding `aside#toggle` to left by animating its left offset instead of toggling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in-built JQuery option for dragging.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Draggable </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery- ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <style>
            #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(function() {
            $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
            <p>Drag me around</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

find relevant documentation [here](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)